# What is the probability it will take more than 20 people..?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

At  airport  security  there  is  a  bucket  with  2  red  balls  and  8  white  balls.   For  each person, the security guard will select a ball with replacement.  People who get a red ball will be selected for further screening.  What is the probability it will take more than 20 people to get the third person selected for further screening

I think that since we need more than 20 people to get the third success then having 0 red in the first 20 or 1 red in the first 20 or 2 people in the first 20 with probability of getting a red is 2/10.

So I think that the answer is $P(Y\le2)={20 \choose 0}(2/10)^0(8/10)^{20}+{20 \choose 1}(2/10)^1(8/10)^{19}+{20 \choose 2}(2/10)^2(8/10)^{18} $

Can that be a correct solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.